# How to load two images in ENVI 5.1?

Tags: remote-sensing, import, imagery, envi

I am using ENVI 5.1 and when I use the Data Manager to load several images and if I want to load two adjacent images, why would one of them load and the other doesn't?. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is what I am asking for but I figured it out. You go to the Preferences at the File menu section and then go to the Data Manager and set "Clear View when Loading New Image" to false so you want to load the image at the same time is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows: Views in the menu and then Create New View. Load your images in different views.